# php - DOM Get elements by tag name including child nodes

Tags: php, dom

Sometimes bad HTML or broken HTML can be found and results can be as unexpected. Say i find html like this

```
<p>
   Paragraph 1 
   <p>Child p with text</p> text of parent p
</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<a href='#'>Link</a>
```

I filter paragraphs and i want this as result

```
Array(
   [0] = '<p>Paragraph 1 <p>Child p with text</p> text of parent p</p>'
   [1] = '<p>Paragraph2</p>'
);
```

Here's my code:

```
$results = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');
$tags = array();
foreach($results as $tag){
   $tags[] = $dom->saveXML($tag);
}

return $tags;
```

And i get this

```
 Array(
   [0] = '<p>Paragraph 1</p>'
   [1] = '<p>Child p with text</p>'
   [2] = '<p>Paragraph2</p>'
);
```

Notice how **text of parent p** is stripped.

Comment: DOM is going to do some basic cleanups on the html when it's loaded, which means invalid structures are going to get toasted. If you want broken html to be loaded, you can't really use DOM. it's VERY pick about broken html to begin with.

Comment: DOM is doing its job as supposed to, i mean imagine links within links. It filters correctly and that's what i want. But sometimes we have situations like my example and we loose content.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually get whay you want in xml mode:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$str = <<<EOF
<p>
   Paragraph 1 
   <p>Child p with text</p> text of parent p
</p>
<p>Paragraph 2</p>
<a href='#'>Link</a>
EOF;

$dom->loadXML('<xml>' . $str . '</xml>');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$tags = array();

foreach($xpath->query('p') as $tag){
  $tags[] = $dom->saveXML($tag);
}
```

The reason html mode won't work is that nested `p`'s are not allowed in html but they are allowed in xml.